# Azure: How to add CosmosDb to VNET properly

Tags: azure, virtual-network

I have a question about ComsosDB and VNets. I would like to add my WebApp in its own Vnet aswell as the ComsosDB in its own. But for me its not sure how to add CosmosDb to a Vnet. According to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-configure-vnet-service-endpoint#configure-using-portal) article I have to add a Vnet to Cosmos. But since over the radio buttons (Selected Network) there is the label "Allow access from" I'm assuming there I have to add the Vnet from my Webapp so it can access the DB.
This is also what I've done and the connection is working...But I'm not sure if the CosmosDb is in its own Vnet (because I never added it to one) or if its in the same Vnet like the WebApp.

[This are my settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vUfk.png)

So my question are:

Are the settings right in term of secruity manner?
Is it not necessary to add ComsosDb in its own VNet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cosmos DB is a PaaS service and so doesn't really "join" a vNet, however it has two options to better integrate with vNet traffic:

1. Service Endpoints - this is where you apply a firewall to the DB that restricts access only to certain resources. One of these resources can be a virtual network. Traffic still leaves the virtual network and goes over the Microsoft network to get to the Db. This is what you have done.
2. Private Link - this injects the DB into the virtual network, it gets a private IP address and traffic does not leave the virtual network.

You have done option 1, so Cosmos DB is not actually in a vNet at all, you have just restricted access so only traffic from your vNet is allowed. This is perfectly valid if that is what you were aiming for, and is probably the simplest approach.

Option 2 is more complex, but will mean the Cosmos DB is effectively part of your vNet. This will be in your existing vNet, it will not be in it's own vNet.

Comment: Okay, but I'm still a little bit confused. You meant I already have an endpoint enabled and this is because in the screenshot under Endpoint Status there is a check, or?. So far so good. But in the Settings under "Private Endpoint Connection" there is no entry. Shouldn't be there one?

Comment: They are two separate things. You have created a service endpoint, "private endpoint connections" refers to private link which you don't have setup. You would use on or the other, not both.